# Wrong icon of Skype in the system tray

Tags: lubuntu, icons

I have installed Skype with snap (and tried with a deb package). When I minimize it to the system tray the skype icon is not showing but instead a settings-like wheel.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H72U6.jpg]

I don't know what's causing this behavior. I checked the actual icon `/snap/skype/148/meta/gui/skypeforlinux.png` and is 256x256. Is this icon too big for the system tray?

Comment: Providing your release lf Lubuntu would help. My guess is it's a modern Lubuntu with LXQt, but some themes for older LXDE can also look like that. It's best if we're told & not guessing. We currently don't know which DEsktop you're using.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)